# missing libgobject-2.0.so.0 error on Kubuntu 16.10

Tags: kubuntu

I just downloaded *craftware* wich is a slicer program for 3D printers but when I try to run it in the terminal it gives me the following error:

```
craftware: error while loading shared libraries: libgobject-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

When I run `locate libglib-2.0.so.0` this is the output:

```
/home/cmstryker/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
/home/cmstryker/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.3200.3
/home/cmstryker/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
/home/cmstryker/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.3200.3
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.5000.2
```

According to *craftware* it should have something to do with me running on a 64bit system.

Anyone any idea how to solve this?

Comment: https://craftunique.com/forums/view-thread/1895  Bottom line: This should be fixed in the upcoming version.

Comment: @CelticWarrior to me that looks like the answer to this question. Would you care to post it as one?

Answer (score 6):

As suggested by CelticWarrior in his (deleted) comment,

> open a terminal and run the following command:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-0:i386 libsm6:i386
> ```
>
> this will then install all libraries needed to run craftware.

Thanks CelticWarrior